# Google App Engine convert db to ndb

Tags: google-app-engine

On Google App Engine, I used to store images in db:

```
class Images(db.Model):
    image = db.BlobProperty()
```

After inserting an entity (say, 'advertisement'), I can use the following to render an image in an HTML page:

```
    <img src="/image?entity_id={{advertisement.key}}" class="advertise" /></a><br />
```

At the server side, the image is retrieved by:

```
class GetImage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        entity_id = self.request.get('entity_id')
        entity = db.get(entity_id)
        if entity and entity.image:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
            self.response.out.write(entity.image)
```

And now, I would like to convert the datastore to ndb, but I am having troubles.

1. Can I still use 'Advertisement.key' in the HTML?
2. There is no db.get() method in ndb. How do I retrieve an entity by its key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ndb.Key.to_old_key()

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_to_old_key

```
<img src="/image?entity_id={{advertisement.key.to_old_key()}}" class="advertise" />
```

to retrieve ndb entities use key.urlsafe:

```
class Images(ndb.Model):
  image = ndb.BlobProperty()

<img src="/image?entity_id={{advertisement.key.urlsafe()}}" class="advertise" /></a><br />

class GetImage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    entity_id = self.request.get('entity_id')
    entity = ndb.Key(urlsafe=entity_id).get()
    if entity and entity.image:
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
      self.response.out.write(entity.image)
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_urlsafe

Comment: But actually, the image field exists in many models. I would like to retrieve the image without using the model name. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Also, the system will be started fresh, so I don't need to do 'to_old_key'. Can I still use advertisement.key?

Comment: using urlsafe will encode the entire key including the ancestor so that should work regardless of if the Images model is nested.

Comment: Well, the template engine complains: TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'advertisement.key.urlsafe()'

Comment: What template engine are you using? try without the `()`... in jinja2 you would include the `()`, django they are left out.

Comment: BTW, is 'urlsafe' absolutely necessary? As I observed, an entity key contains only numbers, letters, and dashes.